# Paradoxical definition?

Tags: paradox, definitions

I recall reading once that the name of the numbers in the set {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9} is related to the number of angles people in antiquity used to trace while drawing them:

[image]

Does not it strike you as a redundant way to explain the names of them figures?

Has this "explanation" been questioned before?

Comment: 0! No angels! (Just my grammar nazi shouts) What is so paradoxical in this definition (description)?

Comment: e.g.: Two because two angles are used?

Comment: 9 has been written with a "curly" tail in order to match the expected number of angles. See [Ad hoc hypothesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ad_hoc_hypothesis).

Comment: See [Origins of arabic numerals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabic_numerals#Origins)

Comment: At first, this is a myth. At second, what seems logical and intuitive is **not** paradoxical.

Comment: First, this is a question for History of Science and Math SE, it has nothing to do with philosophy, and second, people in antiquity did not draw these symbols because they were only introduced by Arabs a millenium later. [Brahmi numerals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brahmi_numerals) from which they are derived looked very differently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar theories have no historical (nor rational) support.

See Georges Ifrah, [The universal history of numbers: from prehistory to the invention of the computer](https://books.google.it/books?id=wxClQgAACAAJ) (1st French ed, 1994), page 356-57 for some fanciful tehories about the origins of numerals.

And see similar imaginary reconstruction, using segments, into [Carlos Le-Maur (1724-1785)](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carlos_Lemaur)'s treatise : [Elementos de matematica pura: tomo primero : aritimética universal](https://books.google.it/books?id=bvPn_HngzncC&pg=PA15) (1778), page 15.